# How can I detect the file format with Jquery?

Tags: jquery

How can I detect the file format with Jquery?
I have a div that will receive a file. This file can be .pdf or .doc
If user upload a file .pdf, the ico in side, need to be 'pdf.ico'...

Can I discover this with Jquery?

My code:

```
<ul class="produtosDown">
    <a href="/file.pdf">
        <li class="produtosDownLi" style="width: 650px;">
            <div class="produtosDownIco"></div>
            <div class="produtosDownDesc">Manual</div>
        </li>
    </a>
</ul>
```

If the file is = .pdf / `produtosDownIco` need to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

would

```
if ($(yourFileHandle).attr("href").indexOf(".pdf") >-1) 
{
   //apply the icon accordingly
}
```

not suffice? In this situation, you are doing a string search in the href attribute of the URL. I offer this solution as its as best I can discern from your question what you are trying to accomplish.

To provide a more thorough answer - here's a URL to the jquery documentation that discusses how to access element attributes https://api.jquery.com/attr/

One More Edit: Please be clear that we are not actually interrogating the file itself. Rather we are looking at a URL. If the file at the end of "../somedir/somefile.pdf" is not actually a PDF but has a PDF extension in the URL - it will resolve "true" as a pdf because of the string ".pdf" being found in the string object representing the href attribute in this case.

So this solution will work as long as you have control (at some level, be it yourself or a business user that maintains the file(s) ) over how the file is saved, and referenced.

If you need to actually handle the file and look at what type it is, you will need a serverside solution which is apt at this task.

But if all you're interested in is assigning a graphic depending on filetype extension, this will perform as intended

-b